# How to replace single quotation marks with "\"?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm building and inventory system and I'm trying to insert some data into MySql and noticed that I get errors when trying to insert things such as *1" Monitor Cable*, or anything with quotation marks for that matter. Things such as part description and the part name could all potentially contain quotation marks or apostrophes.

I know that I can just put a *"\"* before the quotation marks or apostrophe's by using javascript's replace method, but I'm not sure what that would look like.  If anyone could help me out, that would be great!

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`?

Comment: If a quote breaks your script/query than you have a bigger problem (a.k.a. [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). Have a look at [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for what-ever language you're using to write to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you process some sql in node.js and its parts are not directly copied from user input (this will be danger/unsafe) but first you filter input to prevent [sql injection](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/) - if yes then try

```js
let str = '1" Monitor Cable'
console.log( str.replace(/"/g,'\\"') );
```